# pass complex object in objective c using suez

Tags: objective-c, ios, sudzc

I am using sudzc to communicate to the WCF Service. The method expects a complex object("Category") and processes the request.The code for calling the service is:

```
SDZiPadDocSyncService *service = [SDZiPadDocSyncService service];
SDZCategory *cat = [[SDZCategory alloc]init];
cat.categoryId = (int) catId;
[service getDocsByCatId:self action:@selector(getDocsByCatIdHandler:) category:cat];
```

The code for the handler is:

```
- (void) getDocsByCatIdHandler: (id) value {
        NSLog(@"value=%@",value);
        NSMutableArray* result = (NSMutableArray*)value;
    NSLog(@"getDocsByCatId returned the value: %@", result);     
    }
```

Both the "NSLog"(value & result) return a blank result,i.e.there isn't any data in it.Do I have to call the method differently?

EDIT:- I am initializing "catId" in a previous line.So,catId isn't blank.

Comment: When you call `getDocsByCatId:action:category:` on your service object, are you sure that `self` is the correct value to pass as the first parameter?  Should it maybe be `catId` instead?

Comment: @jonkroll:i tried changing 'self' to 'catId' as well as 'cat'.It didn't work,the handler method wasn't called if i change the 'self' to something else.

Comment: so,if i put 'service.logging=YES',the request xml generated has a random value for categoryId.although i am assigning categoryId=1,when the request is actually sent,the categoryId is a random number.The request xml looks like this: **<getDocsByCatId><category><categoryId>114637920</categoryId><categoryType>0</categoryType><docCount>0</docCount><subCategoryId>0</subCategoryId></category></getDocsByCatId>**. Any suggestions to change it?